# Batch search for named_scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

This is an existing code written by someone else and am trying to enhance it. I am a java developer working on Ruby on Rails, so kindly be considerate.

I have entities like this

```
User
```

Delivery entity,

```
Delivery 
belongs_to :user 

named_scope :for_abcs, :conditions => {'deliveries.xyz_type' => ['Xyz1', 'Xyz2']},
```

many such named-scopes are defined.

Now to fetch the deliveries its written like this

```
 @deliveries = current_user.deliveries.send("for_abcs").with(:xyz, :sender, :receiver)
...
...
...
# few other  conditions added to @deliveries
```

finally

```
@deliveries.sort(...)
```

This sort is taking huge sql and giving performance issues. I want to use `find_each`, but `find_each` is only for Active Entity in Ruby on Rails, How can I achieve this (if possible) without much code change)

Earlier I used to do

```
Delevery.find_each
```

wherever it is

```
Delivery.find
```

Now I cant do as it is an array, what is the workaround or right procedure to do that in Ruby on Rails.

EDIT : 
What I tried :

```
deliveries_temp = []
@deliveries.find_each(:batch_size=>999) do |delivery_temp|
    deliveries_temp.push(delivery_temp)
end
```

This gave me error

```
undefined method `find_each' for []:Array
```

#### type(@deliveries) returned ActiveRecord::NamedScope::Scope , rails version 2.3.18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of research for a week and learning about named_scopes by checking its source code. I understood what the problem was. The `@deliveries` is an object of class `ActiveRecord::NamedScope::Scope` . This class do not have find_each method. So I wrote a new named_scope for limit and offset in `Delivery` model file as follows :

```
named_scope :limit_and_offset, lambda { |lim,off| { :limit => lim, :offset=>off } }
```

After this , I called it in a loop passing offset and limit , for ex. first loop has offset=0, limit=999 , second loop has offset=999, limit=999 . I will add all the results into an emptry array. This loop continues till the result size is less than the limit value . This is working exactly the way I wanted , in batches.

```
set = 1
total_deliveries = []
set_limit=999
original_condition = @deliveries
loop do
    offset = (set-1) * set_limit
    temp_condition = original_condition.limit_and_offset(set_limit,offset)
    temp_deliveries = temp_condition.find(:all)
    total_deliveries+= temp_deliveries
    set += 1
    break if temp_deliveries.size < set_limit
end
@deliveries = total_deliveries.sort do |a, b|
```

Answer (score 1):

`find_each` should work on anything that returns a Relation (which includes scopes).

```
@deliveries = current_user.deliveries.for_abcs(:xyz, :sender, :receiver).find_each
```

## Update

It sounds like you're using Rails 2.3. `find_each` is a class method in 2.3, so you'll need a way to extract the conditions from your scope and pass them to `find_each`. I found [an article that looks promising](http://makandracards.com/housetrip-deck/9611-activerecord-namedscopes-2-3-x-obtaining-the-sql-conditions), so give this a try:

```
Delivery.find_each(current_user.deliveries.for_abcs.scope(:find))
```

Also, I'm still not sure what that `#with` is doing. Maybe it's supposed to be `#includes`?

Comment: Edited my comment with what I tried and the error I received. Did I do something wrong there ?

Comment: Actually, just reread your code. What's the definition for `with`? That's probably what you need to modify.

Comment: am sorry, I got no idea what it is , I searched a lot to find a rails term named 'with' but I could not find one. I just ignored it . Totally not sure what it is. :(

Comment: Search your project (and any gems you're using) for "def with".

Comment: Not sure about the with , but I checked the type of @deliveries. It is not array , it is of type ActiveRecord:: NamedScope:: Scope. This seems to be very old rails version .

Comment: This sounds very promising, when I tried `@deliveries.scope(:find)` it says "undefined method `scope' for []:Array".  In errors it says array when ask for type it says Scope object. I am working on this , will let you know if I reach any improvement

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patient help , it helped me imminsely :) . I could solve it differently.